# StatusBar Padding automatically added on setNeedsLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to display a ViewController from the bottom over the current ViewController, with a specific height. Then I added the ability to move the ViewController up, all the way behind the StatusBar. I implemented it with a UIPresentationController. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot - Full Screen]

And now I have a big Problem: When I set a new Value to any label, the method `setNeedsLayout` gets called and the view of my presented ViewController adds padding of 20px to the top. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot - FullScreen with StatusBar Padding]

My Aim is to set the new Text to labels without triggering this padding insertion. Why is it even added? I tried setting the frame and bounds of the view manually, but it didn't work. The property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` didn't help either.

Comment: just add this line to viewDidLoad method , and chck whether this solves your issue : self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: Already tried that, It doesn't help.

Comment: set tableview.automaticallyadjustesscrollviewinsets to false

Comment: Guys. Please don't deface this post. And this post is about iOS, NOT Android!

Comment: the `UITableView` doesn't have such a property. I think only the `ViewController` has it, and I tried setting it there.

Comment: It's my first question here on StackOverflow. How can I remove the Tag 'android-statusbar'?

Comment: @AlexanderHaas I removed for you by rolling back the change. Another user added the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that I just could override the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method. By doing this, the status bar went away. Because the dialog is modal, I needed to add `myDestinationController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` to make it work.

I hope it helps some people in the future!